# find the first occurrence of a number greater than k in a sorted array

Tags: python-3.x

For the given sorted list,the program should return the index of the number in the list which is greater than the number which is given as input.

Now when i run code and check if it is working i am getting 2 outputs. One is the value and other output is None.

If say i gave a input of 3 for the below code.The expected output is index of 20 i.e., 1 instead i am getting 1 followed by None.

If i give any value that is greater than the one present in the list i am getting correct output i.e., "The entered number is greater than the numbers in the list"

```
num_to_find = int(input("Enter the number to be found"))

a=[2,20,30]
def occur1(a,num_to_find):
    j = i = 0
    while j==0:
        if a[len(a)-1] > num_to_find:
            if num_to_find < a[i]:
                j=1
                print(i)
                break
            else:
                i = i + 1
        else:
            ret_state = "The entered number is greater than the numbers in the list"
            return ret_state

print(occur1(a,num_to_find))
```

Comment: You are printing i in `print(i)` and not returning it, and your `return ret_state` is never hit, so the function returns None and you print it

Answer (score 1):

This code is difficult to reason about due to extra variables, poor variable names (`j` is typically used as an index, not a bool flag), usage of `break`, nested conditionals and [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). It's also inefficient because it needs to visit each element in the list in the worst case scenario and fails to take advantage of the sorted nature of the list to the fullest. However, it appears working.

Your first misunderstanding is likely that `print(i)` is printing the *index* of the next largest element rather than the element itself. In your example call of `occur1([2, 20, 30], 3))`, 1 is where 20 lives in the array.

Secondly, once the found element is printed, the function returns `None` after it breaks from the loop, and `print` dutifully prints `None`. Hopefully this explains your output--you can use `return a[i]` in place of `break` to fix your immediate problem and meet your expectations.

---

Having said that, Python has a builtin module for this: [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/bisect.html). Here's an example:

```
from bisect import bisect_right

a = [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 15]
index_of_next_largest = bisect_right(a, 6)
print(a[index_of_next_largest]) # => 8
```

If the next number greater than `k` is out of bounds, you can `try`/`except` that or use a conditional to report the failure as you see fit. This function takes advantage of the fact that the list is sorted using a [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), which cuts the search space in half on every step. The time complexity is O(log(n)), which is *very* fast.

---

If you do wish to stick with a linear algorithm similar to your solution, you can simplify your logic to:

```
def occur1(a, num_to_find):
    for n in a:
        if n > num_to_find:
            return n

# test it...
a = [2, 5, 10]

for i in range(11):
    print(i, " -> ", occur1(a, i))
```

Output:

```
0  ->  2
1  ->  2
2  ->  5
3  ->  5
4  ->  5
5  ->  10
6  ->  10
7  ->  10
8  ->  10
9  ->  10
10  ->  None
```

Or, if you want the index of the next largest number:

```
def occur1(a, num_to_find):
    for i, n in enumerate(a):
        if n > num_to_find:
            return i
```

---

But I want to stress that the binary search is, by every measure, *far* superior to the linear search. For a list of a billion elements, the binary search will make about 20 comparisons in the worst case where the linear version will make a billion comparisons. The only reason not to use it is if the list can't be guaranteed to be pre-sorted, which isn't the case here.

To make this more concrete, you can play with this program (but use the builtin module in practice):

```
import random

def bisect_right(a, target, lo=0, hi=None, cmps=0):
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)

    mid = (hi - lo) // 2 + lo
    cmps += 1

    if lo <= hi and mid < len(a):
        if a[mid] < target:
            return bisect_right(a, target, mid + 1, hi, cmps)
        elif a[mid] > target:
            return bisect_right(a, target, lo, mid - 1, cmps)
        else:
            return cmps, mid + 1

    return cmps, mid + 1

def linear_search(a, target, cmps=0):
    for i, n in enumerate(a):
        cmps += 1

        if n > target:
            return cmps, i

    return cmps, i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    random.seed(42)
    trials = 10**3
    list_size = 10**4
    binary_search_cmps = 0
    linear_search_cmps = 0

    for n in range(trials):
        test_list = sorted([random.randint(0, list_size) for _ in range(list_size)])
        test_target = random.randint(0, list_size)
        res = bisect_right(test_list, test_target)[0]
        binary_search_cmps += res
        linear_search_cmps += linear_search(test_list, test_target)[0]

    binary_search_avg = binary_search_cmps / trials
    linear_search_avg = linear_search_cmps / trials
    s = "%s search made %d comparisons across \n%d searches on random lists of %d elements\n(found the element in an average of %d comparisons\nper search)\n"
    print(s % ("binary", binary_search_cmps, trials, list_size, binary_search_avg))
    print(s % ("linear", linear_search_cmps, trials, list_size, linear_search_avg))
```

Output:

```
binary search made 12820 comparisons across
1000 searches on random lists of 10000 elements
(found the element in an average of 12 comparisons
per search)

linear search made 5013525 comparisons across
1000 searches on random lists of 10000 elements
(found the element in an average of 5013 comparisons
per search)
```

The more elements you add, the worse the situation looks for the linear search.

Comment: What if i want the index only not the number? Then the code mentioned above is not useful right (mentioned in def function).

Comment: Also if possible can you review this code https://github.com/sathwik007/test/blob/master/count.py

Comment: I updated to show how you can return the index with the linear search. Your updated code works, but it could use significant cleanup (see suggestions in post). But you really should use a binary search. If you have to write it by hand, do it. I hope I am communicating how much faster it is than going one by one--on a list of a billion elements, it will find the result in a worst case of 20 (!) comparisons, while your algorithm will take at worst case a billion (!) comparisons. That's a _massive_ improvement.

Comment: ggorlen. Thanks for your insights and helping me out.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept the answer if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something along the lines of:

```
num_to_find = int(input("Enter the number to be found"))

a=[2,20,30]

def occur1(a, num_to_find):
  for i in a:
    if not i <= num_to_find:
      return a.index(i)
  return "The entered number is greater than the numbers in the list"

print(occur1(a, num_to_find))
```

Which gives the output of `1` (when inputting 3).

The reason yours gives you 2 outputs, is because you have 2 `print` statements inside your code.

Comment: Oh if you worry about complexity, I would suggest using @ggorlen 's excellent answer.